# webroot ignored in project.json for a VS2015 web project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx

Is the `webroot` setting ignored in VS2015 DNX with 1.0.0-rc1 assembly references?

I get the default `<proj_path>\wwwroot` value inside the `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` even though in the `project.json` file I have set it with a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/94) wwwroot was moved from project.json to hosting.json